# Can't add new product category to woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi i am trying to create a product category to woocommerce but this error message showing up "An error has occurred. Please reload the page and try again."
Any solution?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after moving to a new server. The problem in my case, was that some of the auto increment indexes were not trasferred automatically. Please check wp_posts and wp_term_taxonomy for auto increment indexes.